# `zsh` and `bash` handle command output differently

Tags: bash, zsh, string

In `zsh`:

```bsh
% RESPONSE=$(ping -c 1 raspberrypi4b.local)
% echo $RESPONSE | grep "% packet loss" 
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

But in `bash` it's different:

```bsh
$ RESPONSE=$(ping -c 1 raspberrypi4b.local)
$ echo $RESPONSE | grep "% packet loss"
PING raspberrypi4b.local (192.168.1.184): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 192.168.1.184: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.376 ms --- raspberrypi4b.local ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.376/1.376/1.376/0.000 ms
```

Yet when I run `ping` directly, the output is formatted identically:

In `zsh`:

```bsh
% ping -c 1 raspberrypi4b.local
PING raspberrypi4b.local (192.168.1.184): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.184: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=7.526 ms

--- raspberrypi4b.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 7.526/7.526/7.526/0.000 ms
```

in `bash`:

```bsh
$ ping -c 1 raspberrypi4b.local
PING raspberrypi4b.local (192.168.1.184): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.184: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=7.613 ms

--- raspberrypi4b.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 7.613/7.613/7.613/0.000 ms
```

It seems that `bash` is ignoring the newlines that are in the output of `ping`, but perhaps the variable assignment has caused this? In either case, can I get `bash` to handle this string in the same way that `zsh` does?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304

Comment: another classic quoting issue....

Comment: ANSWER: in `bash` use `$ echo "$RESPONSE" | grep "% packet loss"`.  Interesting logic... spend a quarter to save a dime  LOL